# A question about the **Type Erasure mechanism** when read the Core Java 11th ed

Tags: java, types, casting, type-conversion, jvm

This is the code example about Generic Programming the author provide in the book:

```
public class Pair<T>
{
  private T first;
  private T second;
  public Pair() { first = null; second = null; }
  public Pair(T first, T second) { this.first = first; this.second = second; }
  public T getFirst() { return first; }
  public T getSecond() { return second; }
  public void setFirst(T newValue) { first = newValue; }public void setSecond(T newValue) { 
  second = newValue; }
}
```

then the author introduce the  type erasure mechanism

> Whenever you define a generic type, a corresponding raw type is automatically provided. The 
>     name of the raw type is simply the name of the generic type, with the type parameters removed. 
>     The type variables are erased and replaced by their bounding types (or For example, the raw 
>     type for Object for variables without bounds).
>
> Your programs may contain different kinds of erasure turns them all into raw Pair , such as 
>     `Pair<String>` or `Pair<LocalDate>` , but erasure turns them all into raw Pair types.

So for the case of `class Pair<T>`，after the erasure it becomes the *raw Pair type* below:

```
public class Pair
{
  private Object first;private Object second;
  public Pair(Object first, Object second)
  {
  this.first = first;
  this.second = second;
  }
  public Object getFirst() { return first; }
  public Object getSecond() { return second; }
  public void setFirst(Object newValue) { first = newValue; }
  public void setSecond(Object newValue) { second = newValue; }
}
```

so if we run the code blow , prints TURE

```
Pair<Integer> p = new Pair<Integer>(1, 2);
Pair<String> s = new Pair<String>("a", "b");
System.out.println(p.getClass()==s.getClass());
```

**Here comes the question** , when i create a instance of `Pair<T>` with wrong type such as:

```
 Pair<String> s = new Pair<String>("a", 1);
```

The compiler can figure out the problem and print this message：

> pair1/PairTest1.java:12: error: incompatible types: int cannot be
>   converted to String
>         Pair s = new Pair("a", 1);

sice the `<T>`is erased to Object and the constructor has become:

```
public Pair(Object first, Object second)
  {
  this.first = first;
  this.second = second;
  }
```

and the parameter type become Object, so:

**How the compiler figure it out the type is wrong?** or **When does the  *type erasure* happens?**

Comment: When does the type erasure happens? After compilation.

Comment: No, it happens during compilation, but the compiler hasn't forgotten the original declarations. @JohannesKuhn

Answer (score 1):

Type erasure happens when the compiler generates the byte code, but the compiler knows the generic types when it validates the source code. Nothing has been erased yet at that point.

The compiler is however aware that erasure *will* happen, even during validation. E.g. if you overload a method like this:

```
void doStuff(List<Integer> intList) {}
void doStuff(List<String> stringList) {}
```

the compiler knows that both will be `void doStuff(List xxx) {}` after erasure, and you can't have two methods with the same signature<sup>1</sup>, so the validation step will generate error message for that, even though the type erasure hasn't happened yet.

<sup>*1) Parameter name is not part of signature*</sup>

Comment: Its also worth to note that compiler does save by default some generic type information to generated class file, but only for classes and members, so you can find generic type of field/method even at runtime. But this information is not really used by runtime except reflections and it also allows later for the compiler to know these generic types even if you are depending on some already compiled code. As I think this is part of information OP is missing.